# calculating values across multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking to calculate values across multiple sheets - pulling multiple values.

Example:

If anything in column D on page 2 equals (a list of variables) then calculate the value of column B for the rows in that column that match the suggested variables on page 1.

Thanks!!

Comment: how many sheets? how are they named?

Comment: Across 2 sheets - page one would be where the values appear. page two is where the raw data is stored.

Comment: when you calculate do you mean sum?

Comment: ultimately - if anything in column D (on page 2) is equal to (list of 5-10 variables) then add the corresponding rows in column B (on page 2) together

Comment: yes that would be correct

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so then please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Comment: This does not give me the values I am looking for - it ultimately gives me a sum of 0 - thanks for your help. I am sure I will be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF($A$4:$A$8,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$31)>0)*Sheet2!$B$2:$B$31)
```

$A$4:$A$8 would be where you have the list of values.